# What is the correct way of handing IAP(In app purchase) subscription plan

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am facing problem in handling the IAP(In app purchase) subscription plans, in which I have 3 options for membership plan....

**Plan Type**

-*Basic*: Free,

-*Lite*: ₹389.0,

-*Premium*: ₹619.0.

If a user selects lite/premium I am doing payment through apple and everything works fine.

**Question**:

- If a user  wants to upgrade from lite to premium, do I need to charge him/her the difference amount(230.0) between lite and premium or do I need to cancel lite plan before processing for premium.
- If I want to downgrade a plan from premium to lite, do I need to refund him/her the difference amount (230.0).
- If I want to cancel a plan in between the year. Can I initiate the refund process.
- If a user wants to cancel all his plan and want to come to basic, how I am going to cancel all his/her plan.
- If I don't have balance in my account, will apple auto renew my plan or will it get cancelled automatically.

[image: SubScription Image]

Any help on this matter would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Not sure about upgrade but for [Cancellation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW5) you can go through from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple used to handle these upgrade operation like this.
Lets talk about your scenerio's :

1. Lite->Premium : User will be subscribed to Premium Plan but only when  duration of Lite plan will expire, user will be charged for Premium plan.
   [image: Illustration]
2. Premium->Lite : User will be subscribed to Lite Plan and will be charged according to Lite Plan once Premium Plan date got expired.
3. Cancellation : [Cancellation policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW5)
4. Cancel Plans : User can cancel subscription from from settings app in iPhone.
5. Amount not available : Plan won't be renewed.

Comment: Thanks @Shivam Tripathi...So it means user  has to wait till the previous plan to expire (means 1 year approx) to avail the benefits of a premium plan ??? If that so, I don't think its correct....Let me know, If I am wrong ..

Comment: I Updated my answer on the basis what info i am getting from apple.

Comment: Thanks Shivam ..Do we need to handle anything from our end in code for these steps ???...If so, Please let me know...

Comment: Check it out : https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit

Comment: Pls accept the answer if your doubt resolved.

Comment: Hi Shivam, Thanks for your detailed answer...Can you post some sample code, how the above popup is coming...I am not able to understand the above GitHub code properly.

Comment: Could u be little specific what is causing confusion to you? Follow there videos setup your details in itunesconnect,You will get same info in alert which u setup in itunesconnect+ some text added by library.

Comment: I have done all section using native IAP methods...Need to show this popup by without using the GitHub library... How can I show this popup ??

Comment: Here alerts are shown on purchase, verify receipt, purchased. As u are not using this library , Kindly check some other tutorials and try to show alert on purchase, verify receipt, purchased,etc

Comment: How you got this screenshot...CAn you send me any demo app with this type of implementation ???

Comment: You can download library demo project from here https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit . Change Your IAP product Identifiers and project bundle id's, you can get the same. Give a try once.

Comment: Plz send me some sample code... I can't figure it out in that  GitHub library.... In my case I need to show this popup but don't know how should I ..Plz help

Comment: In my code library is triggering those alerts. I am not sure how to trigger same alerts without using same library.

Comment: Hi, kindly update your answer according to the latest standards and rules.